# how to make pandas merge_asof include all events not only one

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I have a dataset including the start and end of shifts like this:

```
schedule = pd.DataFrame({
    "start": pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01 00:59:00', '2017-01-01 04:59:00', '2017-01-02 00:59:00', '2017-01-02 08:00:00', '2017-01-02 09:59:00']),
    "end": pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01 09:59:00', '2017-01-01 18:00:00', '2017-01-02 09:59:00', '2017-01-02 15:59:00', '2017-01-02 18:00:00']),
    "employee": ['KC', 'IT', 'ED', 'NK', 'IT']
})
```

I want to eventually be able to know how many people (and who) have been working in specific times during the day. So I try to make a new DataFrame with timestamps of the frequency I want:

```
shifts = pd.DataFrame()
shifts['timestamp'] = pd.date_range(start=schedule.start.min(), end=schedule.end.max(), freq='2H')
```

and [conditionally] merge it with my original schedules as below:

```
mrg = pd.merge_asof(shifts, schedule, left_on='timestamp', right_on='start').query('timestamp <= end')
```

The result looks like this:

```
timestamp                   employee   end         start
0 2017-01-01 00:59:00       KC 2017-01-01 09:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00   
1 2017-01-01 02:59:00       KC 2017-01-01 09:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00   
2 2017-01-01 04:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00   
3 2017-01-01 06:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00   
4 2017-01-01 08:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00   
5 2017-01-01 10:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
```

Now my problem is, at the timestamps between 2017-01-01 04:59:00 and 2017-01-01 09:59:00 when both KC and IT are working, but the mrg dataframe only keeps the rows corresponding to IT. Why is that and what am I missing in the parameters I sent to my merge_asof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need combination of all `employees` with `timestamps` and then add parameter `by`:

```
from  itertools import product

t = pd.date_range(start=schedule.start.min(), end=schedule.end.max(), freq='2H')
e = schedule['employee'].unique().tolist()
shifts = pd.DataFrame(list(product(t,e)), columns=['timestamp','employee'])
print (shifts.head(10))
            timestamp employee
0 2017-01-01 00:59:00       KC
1 2017-01-01 00:59:00       IT
2 2017-01-01 00:59:00       ED
3 2017-01-01 00:59:00       NK
4 2017-01-01 02:59:00       KC
5 2017-01-01 02:59:00       IT
6 2017-01-01 02:59:00       ED
7 2017-01-01 02:59:00       NK
8 2017-01-01 04:59:00       KC
9 2017-01-01 04:59:00       IT
```

---

```
mrg = pd.merge_asof(shifts, 
                    schedule, 
                    left_on='timestamp', 
                    right_on='start', 
                    by='employee').query('timestamp <= end')
print (mrg)
             timestamp employee                 end               start
0  2017-01-01 00:59:00       KC 2017-01-01 09:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00
4  2017-01-01 02:59:00       KC 2017-01-01 09:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00
8  2017-01-01 04:59:00       KC 2017-01-01 09:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00
9  2017-01-01 04:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
12 2017-01-01 06:59:00       KC 2017-01-01 09:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00
13 2017-01-01 06:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
16 2017-01-01 08:59:00       KC 2017-01-01 09:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00
17 2017-01-01 08:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
21 2017-01-01 10:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
25 2017-01-01 12:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
29 2017-01-01 14:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
33 2017-01-01 16:59:00       IT 2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00
50 2017-01-02 00:59:00       ED 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00
54 2017-01-02 02:59:00       ED 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00
58 2017-01-02 04:59:00       ED 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00
62 2017-01-02 06:59:00       ED 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00
66 2017-01-02 08:59:00       ED 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00
67 2017-01-02 08:59:00       NK 2017-01-02 15:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00
69 2017-01-02 10:59:00       IT 2017-01-02 18:00:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00
71 2017-01-02 10:59:00       NK 2017-01-02 15:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00
73 2017-01-02 12:59:00       IT 2017-01-02 18:00:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00
75 2017-01-02 12:59:00       NK 2017-01-02 15:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00
77 2017-01-02 14:59:00       IT 2017-01-02 18:00:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00
79 2017-01-02 14:59:00       NK 2017-01-02 15:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00
81 2017-01-02 16:59:00       IT 2017-01-02 18:00:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00
```

Comment: Ah... this makes sense. Thanks! One thing though, I get an error at product(t,e). This product function that can handle DataFrame and list is not a pure python function, is it?!

Comment: oops, I forget, need `from  itertools import product`

Answer (score 1):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) may be helpful in the abstraction/convenience:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
```

```py
shifts.conditional_join(
        schedule, 
        ('timestamp', 'start', '>='), 
        ('timestamp', 'end', '<=')
    )

    timestamp               start                 end           employee
0  2017-01-01 00:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00 2017-01-01 09:59:00       KC
1  2017-01-01 02:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00 2017-01-01 09:59:00       KC
2  2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00 2017-01-01 09:59:00       KC
3  2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 18:00:00       IT
4  2017-01-01 06:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00 2017-01-01 09:59:00       KC
5  2017-01-01 06:59:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 18:00:00       IT
6  2017-01-01 08:59:00 2017-01-01 00:59:00 2017-01-01 09:59:00       KC
7  2017-01-01 08:59:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 18:00:00       IT
8  2017-01-01 10:59:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 18:00:00       IT
9  2017-01-01 12:59:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 18:00:00       IT
10 2017-01-01 14:59:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 18:00:00       IT
11 2017-01-01 16:59:00 2017-01-01 04:59:00 2017-01-01 18:00:00       IT
12 2017-01-02 00:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00       ED
13 2017-01-02 02:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00       ED
14 2017-01-02 04:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00       ED
15 2017-01-02 06:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00       ED
16 2017-01-02 08:59:00 2017-01-02 00:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00       ED
17 2017-01-02 08:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00 2017-01-02 15:59:00       NK
18 2017-01-02 10:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00 2017-01-02 15:59:00       NK
19 2017-01-02 10:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 18:00:00       IT
20 2017-01-02 12:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00 2017-01-02 15:59:00       NK
21 2017-01-02 12:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 18:00:00       IT
22 2017-01-02 14:59:00 2017-01-02 08:00:00 2017-01-02 15:59:00       NK
23 2017-01-02 14:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 18:00:00       IT
24 2017-01-02 16:59:00 2017-01-02 09:59:00 2017-01-02 18:00:00       IT
```

This returns rows where timestamp is between start and end. If the intervals are not overlapping, a more efficient solution would be to use `pd.IntervalIndex`.